# How to pass a variable between methods without parameters and arguments

Tags: java, class, methods, mutators

I'm having a bit of an issue with a school project of mine. We're supposed to write a Loan class that will do things associated with, well, loans, such as return the monthly payment and the total payment on the loan. My problem is that I have specific instructions for this code that I absolutely cannot go outside of.
Here's the code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.lang.Math;

    public class Loan
    {
        public double annualInterestRate = 0;
        public int numberOfYears = 0;
        public double loanAmount = 0;

        public Loan()
        {
            annualInterestRate = 0.025;
            numberOfYears = 1;
            loanAmount = 1000;
        }

        public Loan(double interestRate, int numYears, double amount)
        {
            setRate(interestRate);
            setYears(numYears);
            setLoanAmount(amount);
        }

        public void setRate(double interest)
        {
        DecimalFormat percent = new DecimalFormat( "0.0%" );
            if(interest > 25 || interest < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("WARNING: Invalid annual interest rate: " + percent.format(interest) + ".");
                System.out.println("Current value not changed: " + percent.format(annualInterestRate * 100) + ".");
            }
            else
            {
                annualInterestRate = interest;
            }
        }

        public void setYears(int years)
        {
            if(years > 30 || years <= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("WARNING: Invalid number of years: " + years + ".");
                System.out.println("Current value not changed: " + numberOfYears + ".");
            }
            else
            {
                numberOfYears = years;
            }
        }

        public void setLoanAmount(double amnt)
        {
            DecimalFormat loan = new DecimalFormat( "$#,##0.00" );
            if(amnt <= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("WARNING: Invalid loan amount: " + loan.format(amnt) + ".");
                System.out.println("Current value not changed: " + loan.format(amnt) + ".");
            }
            else
            {
                loanAmount = amnt;
            }
        }

        public double getAnnualInterestRate()
        {
            return annualInterestRate;
        }

        public int getNumberOfYears()
        {
            return numberOfYears;
        }

        public double getLoanAmount()
        {
            return loanAmount;
        }

        public double getMonthlyPayment()
        {
            double monthly = annualInterestRate/12;
            double monthlyPayment = (loanAmount * monthly)/1 - (1/(1 + monthly));
            monthlyPayment = Math.pow(monthlyPayment, 12);
            return monthlyPayment;
        }

        public double getTotalPayment()
        {
            double totalPayment = getmonthlyPayment() * 12;
            return totalPayment;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            DecimalFormat percent = new DecimalFormat( "0.0%" );
            DecimalFormat loan = new DecimalFormat( "$#,##0.00" );

            String interestRate = percent.format(annualInterestRate);
            String numOfYears = Integer.toString(numberOfYears);
            String loanAmnt = loan.format(loanAmount);

            String total = "Annual Interest Rate:\t" + interestRate + "\nNumber of Years:\t\t" + numOfYears + "\nLoan Amount:\t\t\t" + loanAmnt;

            return total;
        }
    }
```

My problem is with the getTotalPayment method. It can't access the monthlyPayment variable without me either declaring monthlyPayment as a field, like annualInterestRate, or passing it to the getTotalPayment method. The issue is, getTotalPayment is not allowed to have parameters, and we aren't allowed to have any more fields than the three she instructed us to have, which are the three you'll see declared in the beginning of the code.
So, my question: is there a way to make the variable monthlyPayment accessible to getTotalPayment, without making monthlyPayment a field or giving getTotalPayment a parameter?

Comment: Why not just call the getMonthlyPayment() function from getTotalPayment()? :)

Comment: I just tried that, because I hadn't thought of that, and got the same error that I get using monthlyPayment; which is error: cannot find symbol.

Comment: Are you adding the parentheses? -> double totalPayment = getMonthlyPayment() * 12;

Comment: Your class looks weird. Why are all the methods static? If you make your methods void, simply don't return anything: public void setSmtH(int smh) { this.smth = smth; }

Comment: Yep. All parentheses are in their proper place.

Comment: All the methods are static because...I didn't actually think of that.

Comment: Also, initializing static fields from a constructor is really, really wrong. Remember that all instances of a class share the same static fields.

Comment: Do you have a SSCCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling error in your `getTotalPayment()` method.

What your trying to do is call the method `getmonthlyPayment()` when you should be calling `getMonthlyPayment()`.

Incase you missed the suttle difference in my answer you have a lowercase 'm' when you want an uppercase 'M'.

Im not entirety sure if this is your problem, but its the only syntax error my IDE is telling me.

Answer (score 0):

In your revised code you need upper case `M` in call to `getMonthlyPayment()`.

Comment: Not your down voter but it may be that you didn't format your answer to include the method in code format. Another reason may be your answer is too short or doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Nice welcome for first post, whoever it was!  Anyways before the timestamps move from minutes to hours - I wish to record I answered this 7 minutes before @Luke Melaia  ;-)

Comment: It was actually a lot earlier than 7 minutes. By the way I should say: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to get some more reputation, go head over to the FAQ and look through some good answers. Get a feel for how everything works here. And about your answer, while somewhat incomplete it is technically correct.